# how can i compare the size of 2 turtles within my code?

Tags: netlogo

I'm making the game agar.io on netlogo, and I am having trouble with how your own cursor and the other circles can compare their sizes to see who dies when they overlap.

I've tried a for loop within another for loop with conditions, but the syntax never seems to work.

```
to go
  if count turtles-here > 1 and count cursors-here = 1 [
  if [size] of circles < [size] of cursors [ask circles-here [die]]
  if [size] of circles > [size] of cursors [ask cursors-here [die]]]
end
```

I want this to compare the size of 2 overlapping turtles, so you die if the other is bigger and they die/get "eaten" if my own cursor is larger in size.But when i run this, I get a runtime error with: 
The < operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a list and a list.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I really need this for my project due tomorrow!!

Comment: If `circles` is an agentset then it does not have a `size`.  So `[size] of circles` produces a list of the sizes of the agents in the set.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I ended up with this and it seems to work :                                                               to go
      if count turtles-here > 1 and count cursors-here = 1 [
      ifelse [size] of max-one-of cursors [size] < [size] of max-one-of circles [size]     [ask cursors-here [die]]
        [ask circles-here [die]]]
   end

Comment: you can replace e.g. `[size] of max-one-of circles [size]` with just `max [size] of circles`